# How to yield coordinate pairs from a start point to an end point?

Tags: c#, algorithm, coordinates

I want to create coordinate pairs that demonstrates a path between two points. First if it is available the function should make a diagonal path then the remaining coordinates should be either vertical or horizontal.

I calculated the absolute X and Y values between two points. Then if X or Y is greater than zero, the function decreases it and yields the result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var start = new Point(10, 10);
            var end = new Point(5, 3);
            var coordinates = new List<Point>(Coordinates(start, end));
            foreach (var coord in coordinates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[" + coord.X + ", " + coord.Y + "]");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Point> Coordinates(Point start, Point end)
        {
            var difX = Math.Abs(end.X - start.X + 1);
            var difY = Math.Abs(end.Y - start.Y + 1);
            var iterations = (difX > difY) ? difX : difY;
            for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                if (difX > 0)
                {
                    difX--;
                }

                if (difY > 0)
                {
                    difY--;
                }
                yield return new Point(end.X - difX, end.Y - difY);
            }
        }
    }

    internal struct Point
    {
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }

        public Point(double x, double y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is if the start point is farther to the origin than the end point this doesn't work.

```
  // Start point (10, 10), end point (5, 3)
  // Actual results: 
  [2, -2]
  [3, -1]
  [4, 0]
  [5, 1]
  [5, 2]
  [5, 3]

  // Desired: 
  [10, 10]
  [9, 9]
  [8, 8]
  [7, 7]
  [6, 6]
  [5, 5]
  [5, 4]
  [5, 3]

  // If I reverse start and end points the result is as expected:
  [5, 3]
  [6, 4]
  [7, 5]
  [8, 6]
  [9, 7]
  [10, 8]
  [10, 9]
  [10, 10]
```

Comment: Could you provide an *example* with the desired and actual outcomes?

Comment: [LineDDA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-linedda) will do this work for unmanaged code. I don't know if there's a managed equivalent.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I added an example.

Comment: @Jacop: Typo? 1st sequence starts from `[10, 10]` (initial point is *not* included) when 2nd one starts from  `[5, 3]` is included.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sorry, I missed it, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop while checking if we reach `end` point or not:

**Code:**

```
public static IEnumerable<Point> Coordinates(Point start, Point end) {
  int dx = Math.Sign(end.X - start.X);
  int dy = Math.Sign(end.Y - start.Y);
  int steps = Math.Max(Math.Abs(end.X - start.X), Math.Abs(end.Y - start.Y)) + 1; 

  int x = start.X;
  int y = start.Y;

  for (int i = 1; i <= steps; ++i) {
    yield return new Point(x, y);

    x = x == end.X ? end.X : x + dx;
    y = y == end.Y ? end.Y : y + dy;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  Coordinates(new Point(10, 10), new Point(5, 3))));

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  Coordinates(new Point(5, 3), new Point(10, 10))));
```

**Outcome:**

```
{X=10,Y=10} 
{X=9,Y=9}
{X=8,Y=8}
{X=7,Y=7}
{X=6,Y=6}
{X=5,Y=5}
{X=5,Y=4}
{X=5,Y=3}

{X=5,Y=3} 
{X=6,Y=4}
{X=7,Y=5}
{X=8,Y=6}
{X=9,Y=7}
{X=10,Y=8}
{X=10,Y=9}
{X=10,Y=10}
```

Comment: @Jacop: You are welcome! However, shall we *include* or *exclude* the starting point (or shall we include it in *some* cases only)?

Answer (score 0):

You Math.Abs when working out how much you need to step, which loses the direction of your stepping and all your paths can only thus proceed in a positive direction. Instead keep the stepping as positive or negative:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Point> Coordinates(Point start, Point end)
    {
        int difX = end.X - start.X;
        int difY = end.Y - start.Y;
        var iterations = (difX > difY) ? difX : difY;

        //reduce the stepping to either +1 or -1 for each 
        difX = difX/Math.Abs(difX);
        difY = difY/Math.Abs(difY);

        //start off one behind, because we'll increment in the loop
        int newX = start.X - difX; 
        int newY = start.Y - difY;

        //now when you loop, only apply the stepping if you didnt already reach the end
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            //only move if we didn't reach the end
            if(newX != end.X) 
              newX += difX;
            if(newY != end.Y)
              newY += difY;

            yield return new Point(newX, newY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a straight line between the points? From the description, OP gives, I thought he wants a 45° angle until a "wall" is hit, then 0° or 90° respective for the rest of the way (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Fildor yes this is it. I should have worded it better.

Comment: (The concept is the same, but instead of using fractional steps, stop stepping when x or y is equal to the end)

Comment: Adjusted the code; essentially the same as the other solutions now, mind

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: Untested!

This is how I would approach this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Point> Coordinates(Point start, Point end)
{
    double dirX = start.X < end.X ? +1 : -1;
    double dirY = start.Y < end.Y ? +1 : -1;

    double x = start.X;
    double y = start.Y;

    do
    {
        if (!coordsEqual(x, end.X)) x = x+dirX;
        if (!coordsEqual(y, end.Y)) x = y+dirY;
        yield return new Point(x,y);
    }while( !shouldStop(x,y,end) );
}

static bool shouldStop( double x, double y, Point target )
{
    // Basically x == end.X && y == end.Y , just considering floating point issues.
    return coordsEqual( x, target.X ) && coordsEqual( y, target.Y );
}

static bool coordsEqual( double d1, double d2 )
{
    // TODO
}
```

Mind that I left some work to do. Checking equality on doubles has quite some pitfalls, so I left it up to you to learn about them.

BTW: You seem to only use integer values. Checking equality is much easier if you use `int` instead of `double`.